# Get the maximum of functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to get the different functions for an employee : 
with

```
employeeScopeFunctions as (

    select      e.employeeId, 
                es.FunctionId,
                ef.Label,
                c.CompanyName,


                realOrder = row_number() over(
                    partition by e.employeeId
                    order by isnull(es.sortOrder, 9999)
                )

    from        employee e 
    LEFT JOIN       employee_scope es on es.employeeId = e.employeeId
    LEFT JOIN         employee_function ef on es.FunctionId = ef.FunctionId
    LEFT JOIN         Company c ON es.CompanyId = c.ID


)

select      *,
            primacy = iif(realOrder = 1, 'main', 'secondary')
from        employeeScopeFunctions
```

For the EmployeeId=54 the output is the following :

```
EmployeeId FunctionId Label                                  CompanyName realOrder Primacy
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          C1          1         primary
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          C2          2         secondary
54         273        Group Chief Executive Officer          X5          3         secondary
54         897        Group Regional Chief Executive Officer X6          4         secondary
54         897        Group Regional Chief Executive Officer F6          5         secondary
54         39         Director                               VY          6         secondary
54         39         Director                               G7          7         secondary
```

I want to have the number of distinct FunctionId per employee and get the employee having the maximum number of functions which is in the case of EmployeeId=54 3 distinct functions.

Comment: `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, `TOP` and `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want `count(distinct)`:

```
select top (1) with ties EmployeeId, count(distinct FunctionId) as num_functions
from employeeScopeFunctions
group by EmployeeId
order by num_functions desc;
```

Comment: to get the expected output I removed the top(1) with ties and added group by EmployeeId.